# How to use TComparer to sort a list of records?

Tags: delphi, generics

I have a record that holds data about a file:

```
TYPE
 RFile= record
  public
    FileName     : string;
    Resolution   : Integer;
    FileSize     : Cardinal;
    Rating       : Byte;
   end;
 PFile= ^RFile;
```

And I keep a list of these files/records in a TList<>

```
 TFileList= class(TList<PFile>)
     procedure SortByFilename;
     procedure SortByRating;
     procedure SortByResolution;
     procedure SortBySize;
  end;
```

I have methods like SortByFilename, SortBySize, etc in which I sort the list.
I do "classic" sorting.

Now I want to upgrade to the new-and-cool System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer.
From what I understand I need to assign a comparer to my TFileList, like

```
  TIntStringComparer = class(TComparer<String>)
  public
    function Compare(const Left, Right: String): Integer; override;
  end;
```

How do I do this?
How do I deal with one comparer for each data field (filename, filesize, resolution)?

---

Update:
This code compiles but I have an EIntegerOverflow because the FileSize is a cardinal while I return an integer (diff between two cardinals).

```
Sort(TComparer<PFile>.Construct(
  function(CONST A,B: PFile): integer
  begin
   Result:= A.FileSize - B.FileSize;
  end
 ));
```

Comment: When you write a comparer for a numeric type, you should never use subtraction, even if your data type is signed (try to compare `a = 100` and `b = -2147483640` as `Integers`; clearly `a > b`, but subtraction will yield the wrong value). Instead, you should always compare: `if a = b then Result := 0 else if a < b then Result := -1 else Result := 1`. But Delphi's RTL already contains functions for this: `CompareValue` from `Math`. Thus, although your snippet will work "most of the time" if you do `Result := Integer(A.FileSize) - Integer(B.FileSize)` it is still not ideal.

Comment: I see that `CompareValue` has no overload for `Cardinal` (32-bit unsigned). But you can do `Result := CompareValue(Int64(A.FileSize), Int64(B.FileSize))`, for instance. Or just write the `if` thing yourself.

Comment: Why are you storing pointers to the records?

Comment: Note that a file size should be `Int64` if you want to handle large files (>4GB).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - Thanks. If you post your comment as answer I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks. I quickly looked at the "Compare strings" example where they do subtraction and I thought it will also work with integer comparison http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/Generics_Defaults_TComparer_(Delphi)

Comment: @Olivier - You are right but I expect my files to be in the 5KB-30MB range.

Comment: Don't expect that. Just use a 64 bit integer for the file size and not have to rely on expectation. It's trivial to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. I totally agree with you that under normal circumstances that cardinal is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a comparer for a numeric type, you should never use subtraction, even if your data type is signed.

Indeed, try to compare `a = 100` and `b = -2147483640` as `Integer`s; clearly `a > b`, but subtraction will yield the wrong result.

Instead, you should always do something similar to

```
if a = b then
  Result := 0
else if a < b then
  Result := -1
else
  Result := 1;
```

But Delphi's RTL already contains functions for this: there are several `CompareValue` overloads in the `Math` unit (for different types of integers and floats -- but, unfortunately, not for `Cardinal`s).

Thus, although your snippet will work "most of the time" if you do

```
Result := Integer(A.FileSize) - Integer(B.FileSize)
```

this is not good enough: For one thing, not every `Cardinal` will fit in a `Integer`. Also, as noted above, subtraction is not the way to go.

In your case, you can simply use the `if` thing above directly, or you could create a new `CompareValue` overload for `Cardinal`s. Or, you could do

```
Result := CompareValue(Int64(A.FileSize), Int64(B.FileSize)).
```

(Also, as others have stated in comments, you should reconsider if it is wise to use a `Cardinal` to store a file size in the first place. If you upgrade this to an `Int64` or `UInt64` you can write simply

```
Result := CompareValue(A.FileSize, B.FileSize).)
```

Comment: Never mind cardinal, what about files larger than 4GB?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I fully agree, but my answer is written assuming that the OP's `RFile` type is fixed, and in it the file size is a `Cardinal`. I focussed on the sorting part, not the context.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - Nice and complete answer as usual. Thanks. By the way, any idea why in the documentation they (emba) use subtraction and not CompareStr? There is any advantage in that?

Comment: @Migrate2Lazarusseemyprofile: Actually, it seems like [Embarcadero's example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/Generics_Defaults_TComparer_(Delphi)) is sorting a list of strings that happen to be textual representations of integers by the integer values. The comparison function does this by converting the strings to integers using `StrToInt` and then comparing the integers. It compares the integers using subtraction, which we know is bad, because it will fail for many (albeit large) inputs, like the one in my A. It really should use `CompareValue` instead. But in this ...

Comment: ... case the strings are random numbers from 0 to 4, so subtraction will work just fine (but I still don't like it, because maybe some future maintainer of the code will increase the range of random numbers). `CompareStr` doesn't quite enter this discussion, because `CompareStr` is used to compare strings (character by character), not numbers.

Comment: There are several strange things in this Emba example. For one thing, the text at the top of the page says it is a GUI app with two memos and three buttons, but it clearly is a console application! Also, I dislike the lack of `try..finally` protecting the `TList<string>` object. Maybe they did that for the sake of "simplicity", but if so I wonder why they added the unnecessary `try..except`: since the strings are all random integers between 0 and 4, `StrToInt` isn't going to raise. If I had written the example, it would use `CompareValue` instead of subtraction and the missing `try..finally`.